# WSO2 ESB Tracking Request-Response

Tags: logging, request, wso2, response, wso2-esb

I'm working on WSO2 ESB 4.8.1
By observing

```
ESB HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
```

i need to know the connection between one request and its relative response going through my proxy services.

I tried following the MessageID property printed in the insequence and the out sequence of my proxies, but i realize, even if i'm not so sure, that this property is different from one to the other.

So what's the way i could know which are the requests all the responses are connected with?

Should have i to create my own custom property and to log them in the insequence and outsequence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) In the request sequence you can get message id as

```
<property name="msgID" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
```

2) In the response sequence we set the correlation id using:

```
<property name="CORRELATION_ID" expression="get-property('msgID')" scope="axis2" />
```

Refer : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Correlation+Identifier

Comment: i see... yes... great suggestion. I read in the link you posted that response message Id is generated from the request message id, i supposed, but the best way to trace it is by the method you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: is there a case in which the MEssageID property could be null?