# log wso2 esb request/responses to database

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I want to build a logger that logs all incoming requests and their response to a database. For this I created an axis2 module that should do this in the Inflow and the Outflow - I do not want to trigger the logging from the sequences, because then I would need to put the logger in all my services.

My problem is: how can I relate the incoming message in ESB to the return message? I think this is where Synapse comes in, but I cannot find the right properties to link the messages together: there is no messageId or correlationid that I can use to do this.

Is there a way to access the Synapse properties of the message in the axis2 handler?

Comment: check this question which is similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900053/wso2-esb-tracking-request-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis2 module is a right option. To identify request and responses, you can check the messageIDs. And if you want to access request messagecontext in the relavant responsemessage context try following code block;

```
MessageContext requestMessageCtx = responseMessageCtx.getOperationContext()
      .getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
```

Here is a [blog post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/05/accessing-request-messagecontext-from.html)

Comment: OK, this works for linking the response to the original request.

Comment: Now, the strange thing is that in the inflow of the request, the soap body is empty: it is only filled in the outflow, but there it has another messageId. How can I link that?