# wso2 esb how to match response and request from log file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

As I looked at the esb log and tried to find out which response corresponds to which request, I was unable to since esb uses event instead of thread. Any idea?

The ESB log same is below:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-05-31 00:03:23,147]  INFO    {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To:    /services/EchoProx, MessageID:    urn:uuid:4a300fc1-d5b1-4aeb-9068-164e69cdb5a0, Direction: request,    Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope    xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>    {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} TID: [0] [ESB]    [2015-05-31 00:03:27,123]  INFO    {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To:    http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: ,    SOAPAction: , MessageID:    urn:uuid:ff8def98-3ce0-4cd4-a593-9c7b423ff88e, Direction: response,    Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><result>true</result></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Corelation Identifier pattern for this [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Correlation+Identifier.

Refer to the same question which was answered before.

[2] [WSO2 ESB Tracking Request-Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900053/wso2-esb-tracking-request-response)