# WSO2 API Manager, where can I find the log of gateway?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

such as the title, where can i find the log of gateway which is only about the api`s request and response?

in the file of `wso2-apigw-trace.log`,I can find nothing.

Comment: Did it store in DB? but I can not find too.

Answer (score 1):

You can write synapse wire logs to a separate file with an appender like this.

```
# WIRE_LOGFILE is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2wire${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: [%T] [%S] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m {%c}%n
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.WIRE_LOGFILE.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG, WIRE_LOGFILE
log4j.additivity.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=false
```

Comment: thx,Bhathiya. when I invoke lots of API how can i confirm the log is belong to which api. AND how can i get the log of  `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging`

Comment: Since wire logs print multiple lines for request and response you really can't group everything together per API.

Comment: To enable handler debug logs, you can set `log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers=DEBUG`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log request and response with a correlation id, you can write a [custom sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-Creatingglobalextensions). Correlation id can be taken from message_id like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900053/wso2-esb-tracking-request-response).

Comment: thx,Bhathiya.After configration the id,which log file can I find the message?

Comment: `<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <property name="Authentication" expression="get-property('transport', 'Authentication')"/>
    <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Authentication')" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="Authentication" scope="transport" action="remove" />
</sequence>`   I add this on `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/WSO2AM--Ext--In.xml`

Comment: If you need to log anything you need to use log mediator. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Log+Mediator

Answer (score 1):

You can also get access to the log via Log Analyzer UI in Admin Portal.

[Here are the instructions](http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/log-access-in-api-cloud-2/) on how to do this in [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (hosted version of API Manager).

If you want to have details of the calls to the backend and responses in the logs, you need to also add mediation policies that would output the data. This can be done on the second step of API editing ("Implement"), as shown in the picture below:
[image: Message Mediation Policies on the second (Implement) step of the API editing wizard]

API Cloud has these sequences pre-installed. For your own API Manager deployment, you would have to upload them manually. Here are the XML files:

In Flow:

```
<sequence name="debug_in_flow" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

 <log level="full" />
 <log level="custom">
    <property name="Host" expression="get-property('transport', 'Host')"/>
    <property name="Context" expression="get-property('To')"/>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD')"/>
    <property name="Resource" expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX"/>
    <property name="Origin" expression="get-property('transport', 'Origin')"/>
    <property name="Content-Type" expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Type')"/>
 </log>
</sequence>
```

Out Flow:

```
<sequence name="debug_out_flow" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

    <log level="full" />
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="EndPoint" expression="get-property('ENDPOINT_PREFIX')"/>
        <property name="Content-Type" expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Type')"/>
    </log>

</sequence>
```

Fault Flow:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="debug_json_fault">

      <log level="custom">

         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="ERROR_CODE"
                   expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="ERROR_MESSAGE"
                   expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="ERROR_DETAIL"
                   expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
               name="ERROR_EXCEPTION"
               expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
     <property name="EndPoint" expression="get-property('ENDPOINT_PREFIX')"/>
     <property name="Content-Type" expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Type')"/>
  </log>

<payloadFactory>
    <format>
        <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
            <am:code>$1</am:code>
            <am:type>Status report</am:type>
            <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
            <am:description>$2</am:description>
        </am:fault>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE"/>
        <arg expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<filter xpath="$ctx:CUSTOM_HTTP_SC">
    <then>
        <property name="HTTP_SC" expression="$ctx:CUSTOM_HTTP_SC" scope="axis2"/>
    </then>
    <else>
        <property name="HTTP_SC" value="500" scope="axis2"/>
    </else>
</filter>
<class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtFaultHandler"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
<property name="Authorization" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="Host" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="Accept" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="X-JWT-Assertion" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<send/>
<drop/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find those log records from `http_access_<Date>.log`
**File path**: `<APIM Home>/repositary/logs/http_access_<Date>.log`

Comment: thanks,JeewanaSL. In the file of `http_access_<date>.log` which is too many log and there is no respones data